# Android v4.1.2 not working after build (Cordova)

Tags: android, cordova, build

The cordova based app works fine on android v.5.x, but there are some issues with lower versions.

The build process works fine and I can execute the app on my android test device (4.1.2) and the first view looks completely different.

Is this a settings or coding problem?

I'm using cordova 5.0.0

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android 4.1.2 uses a very old browser (WebKit 534.30) so it is not surprising that you are seeing issues between it and when Chrome became the default embedded browser (Android 5.0).

You can fix this with the [Crosswalk plugin](https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/android.html) which turns a recent version Chrome (what they ship Crosswalk with) into the WebView used by Cordova at the expense of 15-25Megs of extra APK (I haven't used it in a while, but it used to be about 24Megs they claim it is now down to 15).  If you want you can carefully craft your html and JavaScript to be backwards compatible (spend a lot of time with [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/) and turn on the various Android Browsers you want to target), or just install Crosswalk.